# How to create nested file and set owner for all parent paths?

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions, user-permissions

I need to create the following file for `www-data` user like the following:

```
sudo /var/www/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

But non of `www`, `.ssh` directories and authorized_keys file does not exists. How could I create them all and set owner `www-data` for all of them by using one (or maybe two) commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sudo mkdir -p /var/www/.ssh/

sudo chown -R 'www-data':'www-data' /var/www

That will get you most of the way (assuming the user and group are correct). I don't think this site will treat your question well for asking something as basic as how to create a directory.